# Django: how to download file from a given url from user?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to let user provide a url and django will download automatically but have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information would be good.

First figure out how to download the url and work on that by itself.
Once you have that down solid, then look into handling the django form and triggering a download.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a url using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

To get the URL from the user, you can use a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Then, in the view, you can do something like

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

    form = URLForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        response = requests.get(form.entered_url,stream=True)
        with open('save_file','w') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content():
                f.write(chunk)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
```

Comment: one more thing - its better to set `stream` param as `True` so it'd not download whole file into memory. `response = requests.get(form.entered_url, stream=True)`, and then read by chuncks. `with open(fullpath, 'wb') as f: for chunk in response.iter_content(): f.write(chunk)`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov, I didn't know about that! I'll include it in my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov I created an API in Django to download zip in that I want to give download that file when a user hit on the API and in that API in getting a file from a URL but now my coed first download the file in memory then give download to the user. can you help me how to give download file without using download in memory?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is you use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/) to asynchroniusly download the files. There's a [site](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) that explains thoroughly how to integrate `Django` and `Celery`